Can I upload a tax provider app to the Shopware cloud?
I want to implement a tax provider for calculating US sales tax as a Shopware 6 app.
The shop is in the cloud (Shopware SaaS).
Does anyone know if such an app can be hosted directly in the cloud just uploading the app? Or would I need an additional external server that Shopware calls when processing the cart?
I could probably implement it using an App Script but I'm not sure about the process-url that I have to specify in the manifest.xml. Might be an indication that an external server is needed.
Any experiences?
Consulted documentation and Shopware Support
